# Node server not connecting to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, webserver, nodejs-server

This is my first time trying to setup a NodeJS API to connect my Vue webapp to my SQL database.

Running my server with this config:

```
const mysql = require("mysql"); const dbConfig = require("../config/db.config.js");

// Create a connection to the database const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: dbConfig.HOST, //localhost
    user: dbConfig.USER,    //LAPTOP-****\*****
    password: dbConfig.PASSWORD, // ""
    database: dbConfig.DB, //Applaudeme
    port: 1433 });

// open the MySQL connection connection.connect(error => {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database."); });
```

Where dbConfig is:

```
module.exports = {
    HOST: "localhost",
    USER: "LAPTOP-*****\*****",
    PASSWORD: "",
    DB: "*****",
};
```

I'm getting this error after a minute or so when trying to open the connection:

```
    if (error) throw error;
               ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\Tomas\Documents\WebServerv2\AppServer\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\Tomas\Documents\WebServerv2\AppServer\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\Tomas\Documents\WebServerv2\AppServer\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tomas\Documents\WebServerv2\AppServer\models\index.js:14:12)

    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18) {   errno: -4077,   code: 'ECONNRESET',   syscall: 'read',   fatal: true } [1]+  Exit 127                SET DEBUG=webserver2:*
```

I've tried the following:

- [SQL Config Manager Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa3Ki.png)
- [SQL Config Manager Network Configuration Protocols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggRuk.png)
- I've reinstalled both SQL Server (SQL Server 2019 Developer) and SQL Server Management Studio (v17.9)
- I've allowed port 1433 on my firewall.
- Different ports or default ports didn't change anything (1433 wasn't set by default)

I'm clueless as to why this keeps happening. I'm sure it's something dumb I'm somehow missing but for the life of me I can't figure this out, so any and all suggestions are more than welcome.

Thanks in advance and sorry if something isn't clear, I'll clarify if needed!

Comment: There is no version 19 of SQL Server; the latest version is Version 15. Also, though I know nothing of node.js, you reference MySQL in your code (and in the tags), but MySQL Is a ***completely*** different product. Libraries for MySQL won't work for SQL Server.

Comment: True, I stand corrected, I meant 2019, my bad!
I'll look into that after fixing this new issue: I cannot connect to SMSS.

Cannot connect to LAPTOP-OJJGFJGU\SQLEXPRESS.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Comment: You don't connect to SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) either; SSMS is an IDE. As I mentioned, it appears here you are using the completely wrong library; MySQL <> SQL Server.

Comment: I got that error when trying to Authenticate myself in the SMSS app. And correct me if I'm wrong (And sorry if I am) isn't SMSS and IDE for SQL Server ?

Comment: Yes, SSMS is an IDE for SQL Server but you don't "connect to SSMS" (like you said you were trying to to), you connect to SQL Server (which you can use SSMS to do). So you're saying you can't connect via SSMS *as well*? You don't mention that in your question at all.

Comment: It's brand new. Last night I had no problems connecting through SMSS.

Comment: @Thom It's "SSMS" Sql Server Management Studio - not SMSS. And note that SSMS is just an application and is installed separately from all the other bits of SQL Server. Did you (or someone else) install the express version of SQL Server? Your comments indicate that you want to use the Express instance while your post indicates the Developer version was installed as the default instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [SQL Server drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/node-js/node-js-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), not MySql Drivers.
2. If you can connect on port 1433 then the config should be:

:

```
module.exports = {
    HOST: "localhost",
    USER: "LAPTOP-*****",
    PASSWORD: "",
    DB: "*****",
};
```

Using the instance name requires connecting to the SQL Browser on UDP port 1434, and the Browser must be running.  But you can bypass this by using a port number (1433 is the default so may be omitted) instead of an instance name.

And Powershell's [Test-NetConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=windowsserver2019-ps) is your friend. eg

```
test-netconnection someserver -port 1433
```